# How to let the user enter the price for particular product in Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: 7, users, commerce

I have installed [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) (version 7.x-2.25).

I have to set the price as 100 Rs. At the same time user will enter an amount above 100rs.

Is there any option for the user to enter the price and go to cart and checkout page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1: Commerce Donate

Maybe you want to try/experiment with the [Commerce Donate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_donate) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> provides a donation line item type along with a donation product and product display.
>
> In addition to being able to create a donation product, this module also provides a donation checkout pane, allowing customers to add a donation to their order as part of the checkout process.

You could use the 100 Rs as your "price", and implement the "* ... user will enter the price above 100 Rs* ..." as some kind of "donation"?

**Note**: refer to [this tutorial/screencast](http://commerceguys.com/blog/using-custom-line-items-provide-donation-feature-drupal-commerce) also for a great introduction to this module.

## Option 2: Commerce Auction

As an alternative, consider the [Commerce Auction](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_auction) module for creating auction websites using Drupal Commerce. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... lets you create auction/reverse auction websites using Drupal Commerce. It uses [ECK](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck) to create a new entity for commerce auction bids.
>
> The module consists of 4 sub-modules:
>
> - **commerce_auction**: provides core auction and bidding system
> - **commerce_auction_field_helper**: provides a field formatter for entityreference fields which shows the count of referenced entities and a read-only widget for commerce_price fields. You can use this formatter to show the bids count.
> - **commerce_auction_lineitem**: creates a new commerce_line_item type, updates auctioned product price and adds the product to the auction winner's cart when the auction is finalized. The auctioned products are added to the cart as 'commerce_auction_lineitem' line_items.
> - **commerce_reverse_auction**: provides reverse auction feature.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you're looking for Auction

> An auction is a process of buying and selling goods or services by
>   offering them up for bid, taking bids, and then selling the item to
>   the highest bidder.

Check [Commerce Auction](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_auction) module

> This module lets you create auction/reverse auction websites using
>   drupal commerce.

Comment: Yes, it is possible in this module. I'm currently using Commerce Auction for an auction site. If @Nandhana wants to use it only for higher amount, can use it. But this module has lots of bugs.